# Set cursor position

Tags: vb.net, listbox, cursor

So i have this code, i need to be able to move the cursor to a position but i need to get the position from listbox,and move the cursor to all the values,after move was done item to be deleted

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Collections.Generic


   Public Class Form1
Declare Auto Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cButtons As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As IntPtr)
Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN As Integer = &H2
Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP As Integer = &H4
Public Declare Auto Function SetCursorPos Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer) As Long
Public Declare Auto Function GetCursorPos Lib "User32.dll" (ByRef lpPoint As Point) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = &H20 ' middle button down
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = &H40 ' middle button up
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = &H8 ' right button down
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = &H10 ' right button up
Private Declare Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vkey As Long) As Integer

Dim speed As Integer = 1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '  Dim c As Color
    '   c = Image.GetPixel()

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim tempPos As Point
    Dim R As Long = GetCursorPos(tempPos)
    ' Label1.Text = "Mouse helye:" + tempPos.ToString + "   :)"
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(80, 80)
    '      Using bmp As New Bitmap(30, 30)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        g.CopyFromScreen(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position, _
                                  New Point(0, 0), New Size(1, 1))
    End Using
    Label1.Text = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0).ToString
    ' Me.Invalidate()
    '   End Using
    If Label1.Text = "Color [A=255, R=0, G=163, B=232]" Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(tempPos.X)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(tempPos.Y)
        Cursor.Position = New Point(Cursor.Position.X + 20 * speed, Cursor.Position.Y)
    Else
        Cursor.Position = New Point(Cursor.Position.X + 20 * speed, Cursor.Position.Y)
        '  If ListBox1.Items.Contains(tempPos.X) And Listbox2.items.contains(tempPos.Y) Then
        '   Else
        '     ListBox1.Items.Add(tempPos.X)
        '   ListBox2.Items.Add(tempPos.Y)

        ' End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Dim D As Boolean
    Dim S As Boolean
    D = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.D)
    S = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.S)
    If S = True Then
        Timer1.Start()
    End If
    If D = True Then
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If

End Sub



Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do... What do you for example mean by _"move the cursor to all values"_?

Comment: So there are values in the listbox, like " 424 , 203 " next line another value, if i want to use Cursor.Position = New Point()  i cant just use listbox1.selecteditem,i need two values,i need help to fix that somehow.I try to add 2 listbox and save x,y  separately but its not working.

Comment: So you're trying to get the coordinates of the list box items themselves, or...? You never set your `tempPos` variable for starters.

Comment: No i save cursor position to listbox,and after i scan the screen i need to have a button what move the cursor and click to all the saved positions

Comment: Something like that :  Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
        For Each i In ListBox1.Items
            SetCursorPos(ListBox1.Items(i), Cursor.Position.Y)
        Next
    End Sub

Comment: Add them to the same line `ListBox1.Items.Add(Cursor.Position.X & ";" & Cursor.Position.Y)` then just loop through it all and split by the ";" to extract individual X/Y-coordinates.

Comment: Yeah i try to add them to the same line but i have trouble with the loop

Comment: What is the problem? I just showed you the most simple way how to. Also, you still never set the `tempPos` variable to anything!

Comment: How can i split by the ";"  to extract X/Y? And its not the full code its the section where i need help

Comment: **[Research will solve that for you](https://www.google.com/search?q=VB.NET+How+to+split+a+string)**

Comment: Okey thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to fix the error,thank you Visual Vincent for help.

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(Cursor.Position.X & ";" & Cursor.Position.Y)



   For Each item In ListBox1.Items
        Dim s As String = item.ToString
        Dim words As String() = s.Split(";")
        Cursor.Position = New Point(words(0), words(1))
    Next
```